# Ubuntu 22.04 not allowing file names to be written

Tags: files, directory

I have a strange problem where after downloading a file Ubuntu 22.04 will not let me name the file until I selected a different folder than the automatic location, for instance it will default to the downloads folder but it won't allow me to enter a filename until I have selected the desktop folder, where it will then allow the file name to be written.

This is super annoying as I often write out the file name only to see that it has not printed the name and won't do so until I have changed the destination folder, does not matter what location I change it to or if I change it back to the downloads folder but it must be changed for me to be able to name the file.

Steps to replicate are download any file with the download folder as default location, ie save as, the default file name will be highlighted but can not be edited until another folder is chosen.

I am using the chrome browser but the problem persists with firefox and brave browser so I am thinking this is an Ubuntu issue not a browser issue.

Comment: When did this start happening?

Comment: With the 22.04 install, has always been this way.

Comment: You might want to look into changing Firefox from the snap version to the deb version.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22

Comment: Sorry should have stated this happens on chrome.

Comment: It sounds like your desired target directory is not writable.  Can you check permissions on it?

Comment: No, changed all of the permissions to create and delete files with no change to the problem. Also the same as the other folders which do allow editing after selection.

Comment: Have you tried other browsers other than Chrome.  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1421336/edit) your question and add details like what browser you are using and if you have tried any other browsers.  Writing out here in the comments will make it more difficult for others to see as comments can be deleted if there are too many.

Comment: The problem is present on any browser (Chrome, firefox, Brave)